# Return a file as dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary

So here is a file

```
APPLE: toronto, 2018, garden, tasty, 5
apple is a tasty fruit
>>>end 
apple is a sour fruit
>>>end
grapes: america, 24, organic, sweet, 4
grapes is a sweet fruit
>>>end
```

This is a file which also has new line characters. 
I want tp create a dictionary using the file. it goes like this

the function is `def f(file_to: (TextIO))-> Dict[str, List[tuple]]`

file_to is file name entered and it will return the dictionary like,

```
{'apple': [('apple is a tasty fruit', 2018, 'garden', 'tasty', 5), (apple is a sour fruit)], 'grapes':['grapes is a sweet fruit', 24, 'organic', 5)]}
```

each of the fruit is key and their discription is values as formatted there. Each fruits ends at >>>end

I tried

```
with open (file_to, "r") as myfile:
    data= myfile.readlines()
return data
```

it returns the file strings in a list with /n I'm thinking I can use strip() to remove that and get the element that comes before ':' as keys.

The code I tried is

```
from pprint import pprint
import re
def main():
    fin = open('f1.txt', 'r')

    data = {}
    key = ''
    parsed = []
    for line in fin:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith('>'):
            data[key] = parsed
            parsed = []
        elif ':' in line:
            parts = re.split('\W+', line)
            key = parts[0].lower()
            parsed += parts[2:]
        else:
            parsed.insert(0, line)

    fin.close()
    pprint(data)


main()
```

It's not giving the right expected result :(

Comment: Your attempt doesn't match the annotations.

Comment: why not just use JSON or XML?

Comment: @DennisPatterson It sounds like they're being handed a requirement and can't change the process (given the function snippet)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you really need `re` and `pprint`. I have tried with an easy list comprehension and some if statements.

```
def main:
    data = {}
    key = ''
    parsed = []
    for line in fin:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith('>'):
            continue # If we get a line which starts with a '>', we can skip that line.
        elif ':' in line:
            parts = line.strip().split(":")
            key = parts[0].lower()

            firstInfo = parts[1].split(",") # What we have to add in the value, after reading the next line
            firstInfo.pop(0) # Removing the first element, The State name (as it is not required).

            secondInfo = fin.readline().strip() # Reading the next line. It will be the first value in the list.

            value = [secondInfo]

            value.extend([x for x in firstInfo]) # Extending the value list to add other elements.

            data[key] = value

    print(data["apple"])
    return data
```

If you encounter any problem with this implementation, I will be happy to help. (although this is self explanatory :P)

Comment: Thank you for your help. but what if APPLE: toronto, 2018, garden, tasty, 5 apple is: a tasty fruit has a ':' in the middle because it consider : as another main key but it's not because what ever comes before >>>end considered as one key and its value. but what if a value has : ?

Comment: @Comp I revised my code (again :-P ) to take this situation into account. `elif re.match('^\w+:\s', line):` uses the regular expression `^\w+:\s` to identify the line hopefully for the key and rest of the line. the `^` says to start the match at the beginning, `\w+` says to match one or more letters immediately followed by `:` and a space `\s` That should not allow a match if `:` is somewhere else in a line that is not a header line.

Comment: @Comp that case is unlikely to happen, because I am reading another line (`secondInfo = fin.readline().strip()`) when I get my first key (assuming that the first line of the data contains the key separated by `:`. However, @Chris's answer is also correct, and much better in handling the key detection.

Answer (score 1):

I made some adjustments to your code (which I gave you in a previous post). I think this gives what you want with your updated data.

The data:

```
APPLE: toronto, 2018, garden, tasty, 5
apple is a tasty fruit
>>>end
apple is a sour fruit
apple is ripe
>>>end
apple is red
>>>end
grapes: america, 24, organic, sweet, 4
grapes is a sweet fruit
>>>end
```

And here is the updated code:

```
import re

def main():
    fin = open('f1.txt', 'r')

    data = {}

    for line in fin:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith('>'):
            if key not in data:
                data[key] = [tuple(parts)]

        elif re.match('^\w+:\s', line):
            key, _, *parts = re.split('[:,]\s+', line)
        else:
            if key in data:
                data[key].append(line)
            else:
                parts.insert(0, line)

    fin.close()

    for key in data:
        if len(data[key]) > 1:
            data[key][1] = tuple(data[key][1:])
            del data[key][2:]

    print(data)


main()
```

The output from this revised data and code is:

```
{'APPLE': [('apple is a tasty fruit', '2018', 'garden', 'tasty', '5'), ('apple is a sour fruit', 'apple is ripe', 'apple is red')], 'grapes': [('grapes is a sweet fruit', '24', 'organic', 'sweet', '4')]}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for your help. I got an error if key in data:
builtins.UnboundLocalError: local variable 'key' referenced before assignment

Comment: @Comp Then your data sequence doesn't match the sequence you supplied in your sample. It's likely that `elif re.match('^\w+:\s', line):
` isn't matching the `line` because there might be non-word (`a9zA-Z0-9`) characters in the part preceeding the colon.